# Using sequelize with multiple instances of the same db

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I would like sequelize to pool connections for multiple db hosts (postgres) so that if one crashes, my application stays up. In other words, I have multiple instances of the same db installed on different hosts (guaranteed to be in sync). I would like sequelize to pool connections to both dbs. Is this possible with sequelize directly? If not, what is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a Postgres cluster and then connect to that from Sequelize. The configuration is done on the server side and will be transparent to the client.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

The connection pooling for Sequelize is defined in the connection, look for `options.pool` in the docs.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to setup a postgres cluster. The reason is because these dbs are actually part of a blockchain nodes (which write data to the db). I would like to run 2 nodes with their respective dbs to guarantee uptime. If I simply clustered the db, then I could only write to it with one node (and it would be a point of failure). As I said, I have 2 dbs that are guaranteed to be in sync. Is there any way I can use the sequelize connection pool to pool connections from multiple dbs?

Comment: You absolutely want a Postgres cluster. There are multiple schemes you an use, but if it's to guarantee uptime I would use one as the primary and replicate to the other with some kind of failover if the primary goes down. This is not something you can do from Sequelize.